# Stockpiles of cargo

Tags: openttd

I've seen some screenshots on OpenTTD websites of what look like stockyards next to industries/stations. How do I create these?

Here's an example of what I'm talking about:

[image: http://blog.openttdcoop.org/files/blog/V453000/abr11_psg141.png]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Those are NewGRF stations; using, I believe, the "[Industrial Stations Renewal](http://www.tt-forums.net/viewtopic.php?p=732942#p732942)".

They can be downloaded and installed from within the game, using the "Check Online Content" button. There are a lot of cool NewGRFs, some containing new station looks, some containing new trains.